# Question in differentiation

Tags: calculus

This may look like an homework question but it's just an example.
Let's assume we have
$$Y=f(x^3)$$
Now taking the derivatives both sides should yield us
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=f'(x^3)$$
But in many books I have found it to be $$f'(x^3) \times 3x^2$$
Which version of the derivative is correct?

Answer (score 1):

By Chain Rule $\frac d {dx} f(g(x))=f'(g(x)) g'(x)$. You are ignoring $g'(x)$ so your answer is wrong.

Comment: But I have one question f'(g(X)) in this case is df(g(X))/d(g(X) not df(g(X))/dx so how can you call it f'(g(X))

Comment: @BlackSusanoo You are asked to differentiate w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: @BlackSusanoo That contradicts what you write in the problem statement. There you have written $\frac{dy}{dx}$, not $\frac{dy}{d~g(x)}$

Comment: Adding on to my orignal question in the book it was given that f'(x)=tanx. Now I think it means df(x)/dx = tanx. Now as we have gotten dy/dx=df(x^3)/dx^3*3x^2.  The book simply replaces df(x^3)/dx^3 with tan^3x isnt this wrong as d(f(x))^3/dx^3=tan^3x

Answer (score 1):

You should write

$$(f(x^3))'$$ rather than $$f'(x^3).$$

Then

$$(f(x^3))'=(x^3)'f'(x^3)=3x^2f'(x^3)$$ is correct if you interpret $f'$ as the formal derivative of $f$.

---

**Verification:**

Let $f(t)=t^5$ so that $f'(t)=5t^4.$ We have

$$(f(x^3))'=((x^3)^5)'=(x^{15})'=15x^{14}$$ and

$$((x^3)^5)'=(x^3)'f'(x^3)=3x^2\cdot5(x^3)^4=15x^{14}$$

but

$$((x^3)^5)'\ne f'(x^3)=5(x^3)^4=5x^{12}.$$

Comment: Adding on to my orignal question in the book it was given that f'(x)=tanx. Now I think it means df(x)/dx = tanx. Now as we have gotten dy/dx=df(x^3)/dx^3*3x^2.  The book simply replaces df(x^3)/dx^3 with tan^3x isnt this wrong as d(f(x))^3/dx^3=tan^3x